# Product incompatibility:firmware is intended to IDG - Datapower

Tags: upgrade, ibm-datapower

Can anyone please let me know how to upgrade the Datapower firmware version XI52 7.2.0 to 7.7 IDG. When I'm trying to ugrade the firmware I have encountered an error while booting the image as **"Product incompatibility:firmware is intended to IDG".**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the correct firmware image and as you write XI52 I assume you have an appliance (hardware) and you can't run IDG firmware in a XI52.
`.scrypt3` files are for hardware while `.scrypt4` are virtual.

The 7.7 version has been renamed into 2018 so you should grab `DataPower-2018.4.1.9-LTS-XI52-2426-7199`